# Beautiful and Awful?

Tags: meaning

If beautiful is full of beauty then why is awful a negative and not a positive? If it fills one with awe, should that not be a positive? (Awesome and awful seem to be the same)

Comment: *Awe* is not necessarily good.  One adjective progressed into the negative direction; another into the positive.  Compare the adjective *awe-struck,* which is not necessarily good or bad.

Comment: Wicked, isn't it.